# Stack unwind procedure failing when throwing exception after calling a function that returns a structure.

Tags: c++, exception, gcc

I have posted two other questions earlier this week, about exceptions and why my program does not handle exceptions. I have 'undressed' my program from unnecesarry code, and here it is:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class some_class
{
    public:
    some_class(const some_class &);
    some_class(const char *);

    std::string m_id;
};

some_class::some_class(const char *p_id) :
    m_id(p_id)
{
}

some_class::some_class(const some_class &p_that) :
    m_id(p_that.m_id)
{
}

extern some_class return_a_struct(const char *p_id); 

int run()
{
    some_class l = return_a_struct("john");

    throw std::runtime_error("something bad happened");
    return 0;
}

extern "C" int main(int, char **)
{
    try
    {
        run();
    }
    catch(const std::exception &p)
    {
        std::cout << p.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

some_class return_a_struct(const char *p_id)
{
    return some_class(p_id);
}
```

The output should be:
somethingbad happened

According to the exception (std::runtime_error) I throw.

In run(), I call a function that returns some_class. The object returned is then copy-constructed into the object I assign it to. So far, so good. But then I throw the exception, and the program never reaches the catch handler in function main. It crashes with the following message:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

If I ommit the call to return_a_struct() this doesn't happen.

Question is: Is this a bug in gcc (part of MinGW latest release running on Windows 7), or am I doing something wrong. Any work arounds?

GCC-options:

```
gcc -fexceptions -g3 test_case.cpp -l libstdc++ -o test_case.exe
```

Comment: Use `g++` to compile and link C++. (You won't have to link to stdc++ specifically, and you can drop the  `-fexceptions` switch I believe.)

Comment: Works fine for me with `g++ (GCC) 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1`.  What version of gcc and what version of libstdc++ do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it's not the answer :-(

Comment: If compiled with g++ instead, IT WORKS :-)

Comment: What is the difference between GCC and G++?

Comment: GCC is a C compiler, g++ is a C++ compiler! Your code is C++!

Comment: Why doesn't GCC complain about the C++ statements I make?

Comment: See [Invoking g++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html).  You can still use `gcc` to compile C++ programs, but it will not link the C++ standard library (`-lstdc++`) by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g++ test_case.cpp -o test_case.exe`